# How to set a custom .cur or .ani cursor in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

I want to make a simple installation script with Inno Setup. How can I load a custom `.cur` or `.ani` cursor file while setup is started? Thanks.

UPDATE: **Changing standard cursors** code is working well with `.cur` files but animated cursor files (`.ani`) are not animating when installer started. Is there any solution for this? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change mouse cursor inside Inno setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480953/how-to-change-mouse-cursor-inside-inno-setup)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends, what cursors you want to change. You may want to change some of the standard cursors. Or the default (normal) cursor of some (or all) installer window controls.

---

**Changing standard cursors**

You can hardly change these for the installer process only, without using some external DLL library.

With Inno Setup itself only, you can change a system cursors. But this will affect all other applications, while the installer is running.

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "MyCursor.cur"; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]

const
  OCR_NORMAL = 32512;

function SetSystemCursor(hcur: LongWord; id: DWORD): BOOL;
  external 'SetSystemCursor@user32.dll stdcall';
function LoadCursorFromFile(lpFileName: string): LongWord;
  external 'LoadCursorFromFileW@user32.dll stdcall';
function CopyIcon(hIcon: LongWord): LongWord;
  external 'CopyIcon@user32.dll stdcall';
function LoadCursor(hInstance: LongWord; lpCursorName: LongWord): LongWord;
    external 'LoadCursorA@user32.dll stdcall';

var
  OriginalCursor: LongWord;

procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  PathToCursorFile: string;
  Cursor: LongWord;
begin
  // Remember the original custom
  OriginalCursor := CopyIcon(LoadCursor(0, OCR_NORMAL));

  // Load our cursor
  ExtractTemporaryFile('MyCursor.cur')
  PathToCursorFile := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\MyCursor.cur');
  Cursor := LoadCursorFromFile(PathToCursorFile);
  SetSystemCursor(Cursor, OCR_NORMAL);
end;

procedure DeinitializeSetup();
begin
  // Restore original cursor on exit
  SetSystemCursor(OriginalCursor, OCR_NORMAL); 
end;
```

---

**Changing default (normal) cursor of some (or all) installer window controls**

```pascal
[Files]
Source: "MyCursor.cur"; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]

const
  GCL_HCURSOR = (-12); 

function LoadCursorFromFile(lpFileName: string): LongWord;
  external 'LoadCursorFromFileW@user32.dll stdcall';
function SetClassLong(hWnd: HWND; Index, NewLong: Longint): Longint;
  external 'SetClassLongA@user32 stdcall';   

procedure InitializeWizard();
var
  PathToCursorFile: string;
  Cursor: LongWord;
begin
  ExtractTemporaryFile('MyCursor.cur')
  PathToCursorFile := ExpandConstant('{tmp}\MyCursor.cur');
  Cursor := LoadCursorFromFile(PathToCursorFile);
  SetClassLong(WizardForm.NextButton.Handle, GCL_HCURSOR, Cursor); 
end;
```

The above code changes cursor for the *Next* button. If you want to use the same custom cursor for all control, you can iterate the control tree.

```pascal
procedure SetControlsCursor(Control: TWinControl; Cursor: LongWord);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  SetClassLong(Control.Handle, GCL_HCURSOR, Cursor); 

  for I := 0 to Control.ControlCount - 1 do
  begin
    if Control.Controls[I] is TWinControl then
    begin
      SetControlsCursor(TWinControl(Control.Controls[I]), Cursor);
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
...
begin
  ...
  SetControlsCursor(WizardForm, Cursor);
end;
```